# Which is the last event to set a control's properties?

Tags: asp.net

In an interview question today, I was asked which is the last event in page life cycle where you can set the control's properties. I said it will be the event (eg. button click etc) or if there is no event then set it in page load event. Then he said I want the last event name.

Which is the last event to update control's properties and why would one use such an event? and not page load or button click etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say its the PreRenderComplete event, since the page is rendered immediately afterwards

Although looking at the [MSDN page lifecyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), the SaveStateComplete event happens even after that.  Though if you were to use that you wouldn't be able to save the control's new properties to the ViewState.

In practice personally I would use the PreRender event to do 'final' control changes.

Comment: I support that statement. The [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) text suggests to use `PreRender`: *"... to make final changes to the contents of the page or its controls before the rendering stage begins."*

Answer (score 1):

SaveStateComplete is the last Page-based event where you can set Control properties. However, SaveStateComplete is not available in Controls themselves, and any properties set there will not be persisted in ViewState. Since the original question related to the "Page lifecycle," I think this would be the correct answer.

PreRenderComplete is the last Page-based event where you can set Control properties and have them still persisted in ViewState. As with SaveStateComplete, though, it's not available in Controls.

PreRender is the last event that's available in both Controls and on the Page where you can set properties and have them persisted in ViewState.

Comment: I have custom control, property not update on custom Handler. I h ave `override void OnPreRender`, `override void RecreateChildControls`, `override void CreateChildControls` ?

Comment: `public string Aviso
        {
            get
            {
                //EnsureChildControls();
                String s = (String)ViewState["Aviso"];
                return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
            }

            set
            {
                //EnsureChildControls();
                ViewState["Aviso"] = value;
                //EnsureChildControls();
            }
        }`